# how do i Reset Transactionscope and commit after?

Tags: c#, transactionscope

how can i achieve this ? is this possible or should i declare another transaction scope?

```
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
            {
                connection1.Open();

                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(NomProcedure, connection1);
                command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //Rollback transaction Here 

                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("dbo.AddHistory", connection1);
                command2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            scope.Complete();
        }
```

i only want to commit the second command

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: i want to rollback the first command and commit the second

Comment: _What's the point?_  Do you even understand the point of a transaction?  If the net result is a single operation then don't perform the first operation and don't use a transaction at all

Comment: Look for usage pattern at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx). You have to simply dispose `TransactionScope` to rollback it, without calling `Complete` (or it will be confirmed).

Comment: @Sinatr there are two commands in the transaction scope, and i want to commit the last one, i can't dipose of the transactionscope and commit in the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the moment you start transaction any change to data is not confirmed until you complete transaction.

If you want to *rollback*, then simply do not call `Complete()`:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    ...
    // do not call this to rollback what you did before
    scope.Complete();
}
```

This can be done by throwing exception while having transaction inside `try/catch` (as [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) suggest) or by calling `Complete` conditionally (`if`).

---

If you want to execute command while still being inside rolled back transaction, then it should be like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
{
    connection1.Open();
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        ... // some commands

        // if you need to rollback and execute other command
        if(blabla)
        {
            scope.Dispose(); // without this further command is also rolled back
            ... // command
        }
        else
            scope.Complete(); // everything is fine, confirm transaction
    }
}
```